# php - how to remove all elements of an array after one specified

Tags: php, associative-array

I have an array like so:

> Array ( [740073] => Leetee Cat 1 [720102] => cat 1 subcat 1 [730106]
>   => subsubcat [740107] => and another [730109] => test cat )

I want to remove all elements of the array that come after the element with a key of '720102'.  So the array would become:

> Array ( [740073] => Leetee Cat 1 [720102] => cat 1 subcat 1 )

How would I achieve this?  I only have the belw so far...

```
foreach ($category as  $cat_id => $cat){
    if ($cat_id == $cat_parent_id){
    //remove this element in array and all elements that come after it 
    }
}
```

[EDIT]  The 1st answer seems to work in most cases but not all.  If there are only two items in the original array, it only removes the first element but not the element after it.  If there are only two elements

> Array ( [740073] => Leetee Cat 1 [740102] => cat 1 subcat 1 )

becomes

> Array ( [740073] => [740102] => cat 1 subcat 1 )

Why is this?  It seems to be whenever $position is 0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally, I would use [`array_keys`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), [`array_search`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), and [`array_splice`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).  By retrieving a list of keys using `array_keys`, you get all of the keys as values in an array that starts with a key of `0`.  You then use `array_search` to find the key's key (if that makes any sense) which will become the position of the key in the original array. Finally `array_splice` is used to remove any of the array values that are after that position.

**PHP:**

```
$categories = array(
    740073 => 'Leetee Cat 1',
    720102 => 'cat 1 subcat 1',
    730106 => 'subsubcat',
    740107 => 'and another',
    730109 => 'test cat'
);

// Find the position of the key you're looking for.
$position = array_search(720102, array_keys($categories));

// If a position is found, splice the array.
if ($position !== false) {
    array_splice($categories, ($position + 1));
}

var_dump($categories);
```

**Outputs:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "Leetee Cat 1"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "cat 1 subcat 1"
}
```

Comment: This seems to work in most cases but not all.  See edit to original message showing an example of what does not work.

Comment: OK, the awnswer was correct but had a problem if $position = 0. Need to write ($position !== FALSE) instead of if ($position).  Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that. That makes perfect sense. ;) I'll fix the answer above.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$newcats = array();
foreach($category as $cat_id => $cat)
{
    if($cat_id == $cat_parent_id)
        break;

    $newcats[$cat_id] = $cat;
}

$category = $newcats;
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this way as it seems th emost logical but it doesnt work for some reason....

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this, but using your current structure you could set a flag and delete if the flag is set ...

```
$delete = false;
foreach($category as $cat_id => $cat){
    if($cat_id == $cat_parent_id || $delete){
        unset($category[$cat_id]);
        $delete = true;
    }
}
```