# Remove all elements from array after element with searched value

Tags: php, arrays, search, filtering, slice

**$week_link_arr**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1-4_1*Oct-2015
    [1] => 5-11_2*Oct-2015
    [2] => 12-18_3*Oct-2015
    [3] => 19-25_4*Oct-2015
    [4] => 26-31_5*Oct-2015
)
```

**$current_week_url**

```
1-4_1*Oct-2015
```

Tried using array_search to get the key and remove it with unset if found:

```
if (($key = array_search($current_week_url, $week_link_arr)) !== false) {
    unset($week_link_arr[$key]);
}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => 5-11_2*Oct-2015
    [2] => 12-18_3*Oct-2015
    [3] => 19-25_4*Oct-2015
    [4] => 26-31_5*Oct-2015
)
```

This removes the key which is found. Instead if key is found I need to remove the subsequent array elements. Exepected output with key `1-4_1*Oct-2015`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1-4_1*Oct-2015
)
```

If key is `5-11_2*Oct-2015`, then

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1-4_1*Oct-2015
    [1] => 5-11_2*Oct-2015
)
```

Comment: This question seems closely related [php - how to remove all elements of an array after one specified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8084136/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
if (($key = array_search($current_week_url, $week_link_arr)) !== false) {
      $week_link_arr = array_slice($week_link_arr, 0, $key + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case your key is the index in the array
So you can simply remove the keys between this key and the rest of the array

```
if (($key = array_search($current_week_url, $week_link_arr)) !== false) {
    array_splice($week_link_arr, $key, count($week_link_arr)-1);
}
```